# ADB server didnt ACK

Tags: android, adb, adt

I m facing a problem whenever i m running my application . it says `Failed to start monitor thread` and : `adb server didnt ack`.

I tried every possible way but it served no purpose.
Here are the following steps i did to solve it:

1. I opened task manager and killed adb and then restarted ADT.
2. in the command prompt i killed the running adb server then restarted it.
3. in the DDMS i tried to reset the adb but it says `Plugins are not configured properly`.
4. I have properly set my path even though these problems are popping up.
5. I think there is not any device issue as even my emulator failed to start.
6. sometime on restarting the adb server error comes as `daemon still not running"

kindly help me out...

Answer (score 1):

What version of ADT are you using?

If you've recently updated the Android SDK, but haven't removed and reinstalled (from scratch) Eclipse, then that' likely the source of the problem.  When Google released the newest version of the SDK, they seemed to have messed up ADT updating.

Removed ADT from your computer (you can leave the SDK Manager installed) and reinstall Eclipse from http://eclipse.org/

Once you've reinstalled Eclipse, follow these instructions to get your ADT plugin working: http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/installing-adt.html

Comment: but i m using adt bundel... not eclipse configured with adt plugins