# Android - adb server

Tags: android, adb

After reading related threads for the following error, still unable to find the fix. I also updated my Android SDK Path in my Genymotion ADB settings. It prevails even after restarting adb-server.

```
$ adb devices
List of devices attached
adb server is out of date.  killing...
cannot bind 'tcp:5037': Address already in use
ADB server didn't ACK
* failed to start daemon *
error: 
error:
```

Other details: I have extensively tried solutions suggested in threads [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26217055/adb-server-didnt-ack), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24973202/adb-server-didnt-ack), [3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5092542/adb-server-is-out-of-date), [4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26431972/android-studio-lollipop-adb-genymotion-issues-devices-wont-show-up-adb). I have post this question only after trying these and still unable to find a solution.

Comment: Genymotion uses it's own adb executable. If you have installed the Android SDK it's adb executable may be newer. Update Genymotion or copy the adb executable and library from Android SDK to the Genymotion, overwriting the old version.

Comment: Instead of copying the adb executable, I would suggest to change the adb folder of genymotion. you can do that from the settings menu of genymotion.

Comment: Is it wrong to ask the same question if the solutions in other thread(s) did not work for me?

Comment: @jay no but you should mention the threads you already checked and didn't work for you!

Comment: I tried every sensible solution suggested in the 4 threads marked above. Any more suggestions anyone ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/39453943/1778421